# Count trailing newlines with POSIX utilities or GNU coreutils or Perl

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed, posix

I'm looking for ways to count the number of trailing newlines from **possibly binary** data either:

- read from standard input
- or already in a shell variable (then of course the "binary" excludes at least 0x0)
  using POSIX or coreutils utilities or maybe Perl.

This should work **without temporary files** or FIFOs.

When the input is in a shell variable, I already have the following (possibly ugly but) working solution:

```
original_string=$'abc\n\n\def\n\n\n'
string_without_trailing_newlines="$( printf '%s' "${original_string}" )"
printf '%s' $(( ${#original_string}-${#string_without_trailing_newlines} ))
```

which gives `3` in the above example.

The idea above is simply to subtract the string lengths and use the "feature" of command substitution that it discards any trailing newlines.

### Test-Cases:

```
printf ''             |  function   results in: 0
printf '\n'           |  function   results in: 1
printf '\n\n'         |  function   results in: 2
printf '\n\n\n'       |  function   results in: 3
printf 'a'            |  function   results in: 0
printf 'a\n'          |  function   results in: 1
printf 'a\n\n'        |  function   results in: 2
printf '\na\n\n'      |  function   results in: 2
printf 'a\n\nb\n'     |  function   results in: 1
```

For the special cases when `NUL` is part of the string (which anyway just works when reading from stdin, not when giving the string in the shell via avariable), the results are **undefined** but should typically be either:

```
printf '\n\x00\n\n'   |  function   results in: 1
printf 'a\n\n\x00\n'  |  function   results in: 2
```

that is counting the new lines up to the `NUL`

or:

```
printf '\n\x00\n\n'   |  function   results in: 2
printf 'a\n\n\x00\n'  |  function   results in: 1
```

that is counting the newlines from the `NUL`

or:

```
printf '\n\x00\n\n'   |  function   results in: 3
printf 'a\n\n\x00\n'  |  function   results in: 3
```

that is ignoring any "trailing" `NUL`, as long as these are right before, within or right after the trailing `NUL`s

or:
giving an error

Comment: I tried something with sed, like deleting all lines that are **not** trailing newlines and counting the remaining ones, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: If the data is "possibly binary" how will you distinguish between legitimate `0x0A` and newlines?

Comment: @JimGarrison In what way do you think they can be distinguished?

Comment: There wouldn't be any difference. Any \n would be considered a newline.

Comment: In the context of "binary data" (i.e. a string of bytes), I don't see how the idea of a _newline_ would make sense. Think of the input being some bitmap image. Of course you could request to _squeeze any run of 0x0A bytes into a single 0x0A byte_. This can be done (whether it makes sense is up to you), but in this case, you need to treat your whole input as binary and use functions provided for binaray IO. I wouldn't do it in bash. Perl or a similar language (Ruby for instance) would be an option, of course. You can also do it in C.

Comment: Well what I actually want to do is: keep trailing newlines in command substitutions. I know there are some hacks to do this, by setting a sentinel value and removing that after the command substitution. But these don't work in all cases, unless one also changes the locale. For some cases, it's enough to simply count first, how many trailing newlines the substitution would have, and append those. So actually my "binary" means: everything that POSIX allows in variables (which should be everything except NUL).

Comment: @EdMorton Was a typo during copy&pasting. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `RT` and without reading all of the input into memory at once:

```
$ printf 'abc\n\n\def\n\n\n' | awk '/./{n=NR} END{print NR-n+(n && (RT==RS))}'
3

$ printf 'a\n' | awk '/./{n=NR} END{print NR-n+(n && (RT==RS))}'
1

$ printf 'a' | awk '/./{n=NR} END{print NR-n+(n && (RT==RS))}'
0

$ printf '' | awk '/./{n=NR} END{print NR-n+(n && (RT==RS))}'
0

$ printf '\n' | awk '/./{n=NR} END{print NR-n+(n && (RT==RS))}'
1

$ printf '\n\n' | awk '/./{n=NR} END{print NR-n+(n && (RT==RS))}'
2
```

Comment: @calestyo you should add the test cases in my answer to your question and test the solutions using all of them as some of the answers will fail for some of those test cases. You may also want to consider the difference between answers that have to read all of the input into memory and so may fail for large input vs those that just read 1 line at a time.

Comment: Added the test cases,... checked all current solutions for them, and all seem to produce the same results.

Comment: Bad news... it seems your solution works only with gawk - mawk and original-awk give different results. See https://pastebin.com/9VdXcL6H

Comment: @calestyo Not all posted solutions will produce the same results, you must've missed some, e.g. the first sed command in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70617379/1745001 given `printf '' | sed -Ezn '${s/.*[^\n]//;s/.*/wc -l <<!\n&!/ep}'` will produce no output instead of `0` and the last perl command in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616543/1745001 given that same input will print an empty line. I haven't tried the rest of the answers with each of the inputs.

Comment: @calestyo that's not bad news at all since I specifically said in my answer that it requires GNU awk (`gawk`) for `RT`.

Comment: Sorry, oversaw that with GNU awk. And yes you're right with `printf '' | sed -Ezn '${s/.*[^\n]//;s/.*/wc -l <<!\n&!/ep}'`, but the poster documented this and gave my alternative in his answer which works, I think. Ah.. you mean the non-slurping Perl version given there.

Answer (score 3):

Some `perl` based solutions:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

original_string=$'abc\n\n\ndef\n\n\n'

# From a shell variable. Look ma, no pipes!
input="$original_string" perl -E '$ENV{input} =~ /(\n*)\z/; say length $1'

# From standard input (Note: The herestring adds an extra newline)
perl -0777 -nE '/(\n*)\z/; say length($1) - 1' <<<"$original_string"

# Or in a shell without herestrings (But then you're also not getting the
# above $'' quoting syntax)
printf "%s" "$original_string" | perl -0777 -nE '/(\n*)\z/; say length $1'
```

---

And a more verbose way that doesn't involve reading the input as a single chunk like `-0777` does (Unless there are no newlines at all), good for large amounts of data:

```sh
printf "abc\n\ndef\n\n\n" | perl -nE '
  if (/^\n\z/) { # Nothing but a newline
    $blank++
  } elsif (/\n\z/) { # Data that ends in a newline; reset counter to 1
    $blank = 1
  } else { # No newline (Last line is missing one?); reset counter to 0
    $blank = 0
  }
  END { say $blank }'
```

Comment: `perl -sE'$i =~ /(\n*)\z/; say length $1' -- -i "$original_string"`

Comment: Note that `-E` isn't forward compatible. I recommend against it in all but throwaway code. You can use `-M5.010 -e` instead

Comment: Won that little bet with myself.

Comment: Though that `-s` trick for passing the value is nice.

Comment: @ikegami *"Note that -E isn't forward compatible"* You mean that sometimes in the future `say` will not be a feature? According to `perldoc perlrun`, the option `-E` enables all optional features. And since the optional features can change in the future, it is uncertain what `-E` will do in the future?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I mean a feature could be added that would cause the program to stop working. -E is specifically used to enable stuff that's not backwards compatible

Comment: Your slurping solution seems similar to the one from @tshiono below. May I was for which reason you use \z instead of $ ? AFAIU, these should be identical unless the m modifier is used? Thanks :-)

Comment: @calestyo `\z` and `$` aren't identical. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Metacharacters and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Assertions

Comment: But the "Assertions" chapter says "The \A and \Z are just like "^" and "$", except that they won't match multiple times when the /m modifier is used, while "^" and "$" will match at every internal line boundary. To match the actual end of the string and not ignore an optional trailing newline, use \z." ... and you don't use /m ? tshiono’s answer is more or less like yours just with $... and I found no case in which his wouldn't work? So for which case exactly did you do it?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed we can use the `-z` option, plus the `e` modifier of the substitute command and pack all this in a single sed script:

```sh
$ printf 'abc\n\n\def\n\n\n' | sed -Ezn '${s/.*[^\n]//;s/.*/wc -l <<!\n&!/ep}'
3
```

Or, if the string is in a variable:

```sh
$ printf '%s' "$original_string" | sed -Ezn '${s/.*[^\n]//;s/.*/wc -l <<!\n&!/ep}'
3
```

Explanations:

- The `-z` option tells sed that input lines are terminated by the NUL character instead of newline.
- The `-n` option disables the automatic printing.
- The 2 substitute commands are applied to the last line only (the `$` address), that is, everything after the last NUL character or, if there is no NUL character, the complete input string.
- The first substitute command deletes everything except the trailing newlines.
- The second substitute command replaces these trailing newlines by:

  ```sh
  wc -l <<!



  !
  ```

  with as many lines in the here-document as there are trailing newlines in the input. As the `e` modifier is used, this new pattern space is executed, the pattern space is replaced by the result and printed (thanks to the `p` modifier).

##### Edit

As noticed by the OP this produces no output at all when the input is the empty string, instead of the expected `0`. A simpler version, that also works with the empty string could be:

```sh
$ printf '%s' "$original_string" | sed -zn '${s/.*[^\n]//;p;}' | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice. There's just one case where it doesn't work, the empty string.
I think one can also write it as sed --zero-terminated -E -n '${s/^.*[^\n]//;p}' | wc -l  ... which even works for the empty string.

Comment: @calestyo Yes, you're right, I forgot to consider this case. Your version with piping to `wc -l` is better. I'll add an edit about this.

Comment: btw: -E is not necessary, and p should be followed by ; to be more posixly correct (though this uses anyway 1-2 GNU extensions)

Answer (score 2):

How about another perl solution:

```
echo -ne 'abc\n\n\def\n\n\n' | perl -0777 -ne '/\n*$/; print length($&), "\n";'
=> 3
echo -ne '\n' | perl -0777 -ne '/\n*$/; print length($&), "\n";'
=> 1
echo -ne '\n\n' | perl -0777 -ne '/\n*$/; print length($&), "\n";'
=> 2
echo -ne 'a\n\n' | perl -0777 -ne '/\n*$/; print length($&), "\n";'
=> 2
echo -ne 'a' | perl -0777 -ne '/\n*$/; print length($&), "\n";'
=> 0
```

- The `-0777` option tells perl to slurp all input lines at once.
- The `-ne` option is similar to that of sed.
- The regex `\n*$` matches trailing newlines of the input string.
- The perl variable `$&` is assigned to the matched substring.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for the case of a single [trailing] newline.
printf '\n' => 0 (should be 1), printf '\n\n' => 1 (should be 2).
Same when there is some letter ahead of the '\n':
printf 'a\n' => 0 (should be 1), printf 'a\n\n' => 1 (should be 2).

Comment: Thank you for the polite feedback. I may have misunderstood the definition
of the `trailing newlines`. I've updated my answer with the corrected
answer. BR.